# Defining a general width for table columns in CSS

Tags: css

How can I define some general properties for the columns of a table? For example, in the following table I have 2 columns. I want the left column to have a width of 30px and the right column a width of 70px. For the example below I'm writing a CSS class name in every row. Is there a way that I can do it in a more general way? Thanks.

```
<table width="100px" cellspacing="0">
            <tbody>
                <tr>                
                    <td class="left">30px wide</td>
                    <td class="right">70px wide</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>                
                    <td class="left">30px wide</td>
                    <td class="right">70px wide</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>                
                    <td class="left">30px wide</td>
                    <td class="right">70px wide</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>                
                    <td class="left">30px wide</td>
                    <td class="right">70px wide</td>
                </tr>       

            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

it suffices to define the first TD's... it looks like:

```
<table width="100px" cellspacing="0">
            <tbody>
                <tr>                
                    <td class="left">30px wide</td>
                    <td class="right">70px wide</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>                
                    <td>30px wide</td>
                    <td>70px wide</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>                
                    <td>30px wide</td>
                    <td>70px wide</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>                
                    <td>30px wide</td>
                    <td>70px wide</td>
                </tr>       

            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

> And in following, Im writing css class name in every row. Is there a way that I can do it in more general way?

I assume you mean "... in every *column*". No, if you want cross-browser support, this is currently indeed the only way to do it.

In CSS 3, there is the [`:nth-child`](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/nthchild.html) pseudo-class, but it is fully supported only by [FF >= 3.5 and Chrome.](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html)

Answer (score 0):

Just define classes for `td` in first row. See [example](http://jsfiddle.net/gorsky/CqLYd/).

Answer (score 0):

Use `<th>` tags for the first row of the table and then you could have:

```
th.left {
 width: 30px;
}

th.right {
 width: 70px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<col>` elements to define widths for a column at a time.  Something like

```
<table>
 <col class="left">
 <col class="right">
 <tr>
  <td>30px wide</td>
  <td>70px wide</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>30px wide</td>
  <td>70px wide</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Note, though, the styles you can set are quite limited -- so far, only `width` and `background-color` work for me (in Chrome 9).  So if you have anything else set for the class (font sizes, text colors, alignment, etc), you might want to stick to keeping the class on each `<td>`.